# Java Class variable's declaration from other variable

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a java domain class that models a table in the database, I have two fields
Double Budget1
Double Budget 2
I need to add another field in the class as a member variable
Double totalBudget which is some of budget1 and budget2, how can I do this in java8?

```
@Formula("(SELECT SUM(c.budget1) FROM table1)
private Double budget1;

@Formula("(SELECT SUM(c.budget2) FROM table2)
private Double budget2;

@Transient
private Double totalBudget = budget1 + budget2;
```

This gives me an error

Comment: And which error this code gives you?

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test object

Comment: Are you sure you really need that field? I would go with a method which returns their sum. Keep in mind you should update the `totalBudget` every time either the `budget1` or `budget2` is changed

Comment: @Kanub, add the full stacktrace, please

Comment: You don't want to do any of this. (1) You should be using `BigDecimal`, not `Double`, for money, and `DECIMAL` in the database; (2) you don't want a field whose value can be inferred from other fields. All you need is a *getter* for the field that returns the sum of the values. Or else (3) if the oject is immutable, you want to compute the sum in the SQL statement that fetches these values.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need a field whose value can be inferred from other fields. You should use a getter without a field:

```
public Double getTotalBudget()
{
    return budget1+budget2;
}
```

or if the object is immutable, even a query:

```
@Formula("(SELECT SUM(c.budget1)+SUM(c.budget2) FROM table2)")
private Double totalBudget;
```

Of course you should be using `BigDecimal`, not `Double`, for money, and `DECIMAL` in the database.

Comment: Running a query for a sum would be a very bad idea

Comment: In hibernate when he gets the object it will be already populated. Why extra computation?

Comment: @PritamBanerjee Yes, it will be already populated with the result of the three queries. The computation has to be done somewhere.

Comment: Rather it would be better that he gets the other two fields and then get the totalBudget

Comment: @PritamBanerjee 'Very bad idea' and 'better' are not factual statements or arguments.